# GYROSCOPE does not work after update to 2.3.5

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

My code used to work on 2.2, and I was able to get the gyroscope data, but after the update to 2.3, it does not work anymore. I also tried on a galaxy player to make sure it's not a hardware issue with my phone. It did not work on that one either. Any suggestions? Here's the code:

```
    package my.acc;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    
    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    
    public class myact extends Activity {
        
        private SensorManager mSensorManager;
        Sensor myAcc, myAcc2, myAcc3, myAcc4;
        MySensorListener listener, listener2,listener3, listener4;
        EditText mEdit;
    
    
        
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            
            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.activity_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    
            
            // Set up the accelerometer reading
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            myAcc = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
            myAcc2 = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
            myAcc3 = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
            myAcc4 = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    
            final ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
            mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
    
            togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                PrintWriter mCurrentFile = null;
                PrintWriter mCurrentFile2 = null;
                PrintWriter mCurrentFile3 = null;
                PrintWriter mCurrentFile4 = null;
    
    
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on clicks
                    if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {

                        String strname = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (strname.equals("Select Activity")){
                            strname = mEdit.getText().toString();
                        }
                        String nameStr  = new String("/sdcard/" + strname + "acc" + ".csv");
                        String nameStr2 = new String("/sdcard/" + strname + "gyr" + ".csv");
                        String nameStr3 = new String("/sdcard/" + strname + "ori" + ".csv");
                        String nameStr4 = new String("/sdcard/" + strname + "gra" + ".csv");
    
                        File outputFile = new File(nameStr);
                        File outputFile2 = new File(nameStr2);
                        File outputFile3 = new File(nameStr3);
                        File outputFile4 = new File(nameStr4);
                        
                        try {
                            mCurrentFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                            mCurrentFile2 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile2));
                            mCurrentFile3 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile3));
                            mCurrentFile4 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile4));
    
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                        mSensorManager.registerListener(listener = new MySensorListener(mCurrentFile), myAcc , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
                        mSensorManager.registerListener(listener2 = new MySensorListener(mCurrentFile2), myAcc2 , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
                        mSensorManager.registerListener(listener3 = new MySensorListener(mCurrentFile3), myAcc3 , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
                        mSensorManager.registerListener(listener4 = new MySensorListener(mCurrentFile4), myAcc4 , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    
                        //mSensorManager.registerListener(listener, myAcc2 , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    
                    } else {
                        

                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener, myAcc);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener2, myAcc2);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener3, myAcc3);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener4, myAcc4);
                        mCurrentFile.close();
                        mCurrentFile2.close();
                        mCurrentFile3.close();
                        mCurrentFile4.close();
                        

    
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

> ```
> package my.acc;
>
> import java.io.PrintWriter;
>
> import android.hardware.Sensor;
> import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
> import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
>
> public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener {
>
>     String comma = new String(",");
>   private PrintWriter mCurrentFile;
>   
>     public MySensorListener( PrintWriter mCurrentFile){
>       //Creating a file to print the data into
>        
>       this.mCurrentFile = mCurrentFile;
>
>     }
>
>     
>     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>     }
>
>
>     
>     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
>         
>         StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
>
>         buff.append(String.valueOf(event.sensor.getName()));     
>         buff.append(comma);
>
>
>         buff.append(String.valueOf(event.timestamp));
>         
>
>         buff.append(comma);
>
>           buff.append(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
>           buff.append(comma);
>           buff.append(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
>           buff.append(comma);
>           buff.append(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));
>
>         mCurrentFile.println(buff.toString());
>         mCurrentFile.flush();
>         
>
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

I even reported as a bug to google here is their response:

> those aren't Google devices, so you'll have to talk to Samsung

Comment: What values do you get logged from the gyro sensor, absolutely zero, or just very small values?

Comment: @NickT nothing. it does not even register my gyroscpe sensor. the listener is not called at all.

Comment: Not sure if it is just a Samsung issue. I have observed just the same problem on a LG-P970 phone. With Android 2.2 the gyroscope worked right, but after the update to Android 2.3 the gyroscope readings are always zero. Worst of all are users giving negative votes to your applications due to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be just a Samsung issue. Filing the issue with Google did not help; they referred me back to Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can help, but it seems to be related to your problem: gyroscope does not work flashing rom. You can have a look ([Galaxy S2 - Gyro & Compass not working](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1262918)) and try to run the proposed test.